# Not able to make the Webview editable

Tags: javascript, webview, uwp, contenteditable

I'm trying to get the **webview** control into editable mode (for UWP). Here's my code where I am injecting the js to do that:

```
private const string EditableParameter = "~editable~";
private const string SetBodyEditableScript = @"
        try
        {  
            document.body.contentEditable = '" + EditableParameter + @"';
        }
        catch(e)
        {

        }";

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    MakeWebviewEditable();
}

private const string EventNotificationFormat = @"window.external.notify('{0}');";
private async void MakeWebviewEditable()
{
    await InjectJavaScriptAsync(SetBodyEditableScript.Replace(EditableParameter, "true"));
}

private async Task InjectJavaScriptAsync(string jscript)
        {
            await WebView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
            {
                try
                {                        
                        string result = await WebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { jscript });
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            });
        }
```

But it doesn't work and the `webview` control is still not `editable`.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be pretty simple. Just had to set the designmode to true:

```
document.designMode='on';
```